# back button don't close the search result activity and i have to press several times to get back to mainActivity

Tags: android

I create search Interface in the toolbar , every thing is good and when i press the back button in toolbar , it work's good and get back to main activity , but when i press the hardware back button , i have to press several times until get back to the main activity :

this is my `MainActivity` :

```
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import app.bahaltarinha.com.R;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //=====================================================  onCreateMethod()
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //setupToolbar
        setUpToolbar();

    }

    //=====================================================  setupToolbar Method()
    private void setUpToolbar() {

        Toolbar mainToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.xmlToolbarMain);
        setSupportActionBar(mainToolbar);


        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.mipmap.ic_menu);

    }

    //=====================================================  onCreateOptionsMenu Method()
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main , menu);


        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search_toolbar);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);

        return true;
    }
    //=====================================================  onOptionsItemSelected Method()


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_search_toolbar:
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the `SearchResultActivity`:

```
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import app.bahaltarinha.com.R;

/**
 * Created by majid on 1/8/2016.
 */
public class SearchResultsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView txtSearchQuery;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);

        setUpToolbar();

        txtSearchQuery = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtSearchQuery);
        handleIntent(getIntent());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search_toolbar);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);

        return true;
    }

    private void setUpToolbar() {

        Toolbar mainToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.xmlToolbarSearchActivity);
        setSupportActionBar(mainToolbar);


        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())){
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            doSearchQuery(query);
        }
    }

    private void doSearchQuery(String query) {
        txtSearchQuery.setText(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

and this is `androidManifest`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="app.bahaltarinha.com">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!-- MainActivity -->

        <activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value=".activities.SearchResultsActivity"/>
        </activity>

        <!-- Search Results Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.SearchResultsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                    android:name="android.app.searchable"
                    android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Ok , i find the solution and we should use intent for that :

we should write in `onBackPressed()` in SearchResultActivity:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        startActivity(new Intent(SearchResultsActivity.this , MainActivity.class));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the below code from your SearchResultsActivity.JAVA. You no need to define it. By default System will automatically finish the current activity when you press back.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        this.finish();
    }
```

and there is not need of intent filter in the Manifest for this activity. Kindly remove them too.

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Hope this will help you..!!

Comment: i delete intent filter code in android manifest , but search view don't work with new codes.